# Value of unknown in linear system Ax=b

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I am reviewing for an exam and came across this question. I attempted to solve it by setting up a system from $~Ax=b~$, which results in the system

$$x + z = 1 $$
$$4x + y + c_1z = 0 $$ 
$$c_2y + z = 0  $$

I'm not sure if I'm making simple algebra mistakes after looking at this too long, but I can't seem to get $~c_1~$ and $~c_2~$ together in a meaningful way to cancel them out.

I'm also not sure how det$A=2~$ is useful.

I know the answer is $~C~$ from the answer key but not how to get there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could find an expression for the determinant in terms of $c_1$ and $c_2$ and use the information that $\det A=2$ and $c_1c_2=3$ to find $c_1$ and $c_2$; then solve the linear system to get $x=-\dfrac32$

Comment: Oops, I meant $x=-1$

Comment: Please take the time to enter important parts of your question as text instead of pasting a picture: your question should be comprehensible with images disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&1\\
4&1&c_1\\
0&c_2&1\\
\end{pmatrix}=-c_1c_2+4c_2+1=2$$

as given above. Also since we're given $c_1c_2=3$ we have $$\det(A)=-(3)+4c_2+1=2\iff c_2=1$$

Further since $c_2=1$ this implies by the relation $c_1c_2=3$ that $c_1=3.$

Now you should easily be able to retrieve $x$ by Gaussian elimination as normal since the determinant is nonzero by assumption.

I used [The Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) method to calculate the determinant of matrix $A$.

Answer (score 1):

[Cramer's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) could prove useful here.

We are studying the system $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ where
\begin{align*}
A &= \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 4 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & c_{2} \\
1 & c_{1} & 1
\end{array}\right] & \vec{x} &= \left[\begin{array}{r}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}\right] & \vec{b} &= \left[\begin{array}{r}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
We are also told that $\det(A)=2$ and that $c_1c_2=3$.

According to Cramer's Rule, we have
$$
x
= \frac{\det\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 4 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & c_{2} \\
0 & c_{1} & 1
\end{array}\right]}{\det(A)}
= \frac{-c_{1} c_{2} + 1}{2}
= \frac{-2}{2}
=-1
$$